# Open-source code style checker/beautifier for Linux

Tags: linux, open-source, software-development, code-beautification

I'm looking for a tool that would check and fix programming-code style/formatting, work (at least) with PHP, JavaScript, HTML and CSS, be available for Linux and open source. Ideally it should be as simple, small and quick as possible, but also offer wide range of customizations (which can be done in its code - that's why I want it to be open source).

Anyone knows anything like this?